# Is there a way to retrieve a list of items which you have more than one copy?

Tags: team-fortress-2

The [backpack examiner](http://www.tf2items.com/item/schema/) oddly doesn't do that.

Is there any other site which offers that service, or maybe even an in-game interface I have somehow missed?

Comment: It is very nice to sort your unique items by class manually starting from 2nd page, and put duplicates to the 1st page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [tf2ls](http://tf2ls.com/) and choose the "Extras" option, or "Text Output" for text instead of icons.

Comment: That's great too!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [TF2Toolbox](http://tf2toolbox.com/) and set it to Plaintext and look for 'x2' and 'x3', etc.

Comment: Even better, it has a checkbox "Only show weapons with duplicates"! It doesn't perfectly work (it still shows *some* non-duplicate ones for some reason), but it still is great, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Opening the crafting interface, going to the last tab and choosing Custom Blueprint (last option), then selecting one of the empty boxes at the right will show you how many of each item you have.

Beware, though, that it doesn't always separate out the different qualities of items.

Comment: I found the same thing on "smelt class weapons", but it has — to a lesser extent — the same problem as tf2items, as pointed out to @CruelCow: it doesn't allow me to list *only* the duplicate ones. Acceptable, though.

Comment: Smelt Class Weapons doesn't list hats/misc items.  Also, the crafting system doesn't list uncraftable items in either box.

Comment: Now I'm tempted to learn the Steam web API just so I can create a tool to list duplicate items.

Comment: that would be quite interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, [tf2items.com](http://tf2items.com) does offer this. Go to tf2items.com and enter you profile ID. (If you don't have a profile ID set up, just copy the link to your community page)

On your backpack page it will show 3 different tabs, the last one - checklist - should be exactly what you need.

Comment: True, but it doesn't allow me to list *only* the duplicates, so I have to browse the whole long badly organised list.